# How to find out the .exe running behind a service with cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, service, windows-command-prompt

If I see svchost.exe having the PID 840, how do I get the information which .exe runs behind the service with cmd.exe on Windows Server 2003? If possible without Sysinternals tools.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense as written.  If you see svchost.exe with the PID 840, the .exe is svchost.exe.  Do you mean that you want to know which service(s) the process is providing?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, that's what I meant. Maybe that was a bit confusing, but in fact svchost.exe just hosts services which are .exe again, at least they're executable files.

Comment: It isn't common to say .exe as a shortcut for executable, unless you actually mean an .exe file.  In this case the bulk of the code for each service lives in a DLL file; did you want to know the name of the DLL file(s), or just the name of the service(s)?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. If possible both, the name of the DLL file(s) and the name of the service(s).

Comment: I don't know of a specific command line function to retrieve the DLL name, but you can query the registry: reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{service name}\Parameters /v ServiceDLL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a commandline:

```
tasklist /svc
```